# LUA scripting no recoil

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech-gaming-software

I have this code and I want the repeat loop to get activated after the Right click is pressed for more than .1 seconds otherwise not to get activated OR the loop to stop entirely once I release the Right click after .1 seconds both will work I suppose. Any ideas?

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
 if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
        Sleep(30)
        repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-9, 12)
        Sleep(5)
        MoveMouseRelative(9, -9)
        Sleep(5)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the repeat loop to get activated after the Right click is pressed for more than .1 seconds otherwise not to get activated

You can use the following code to accomplish this goal:

```
local RMB_tm = math.huge

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then
      RMB_tm = GetRunningTime()
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 2 then
      RMB_tm = math.huge
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 
      and GetRunningTime() - RMB_tm > 100 and IsKeyLockOn("capslock") 
   then
      Sleep(30)
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(-9, 12)
         Sleep(5)
         MoveMouseRelative(9, -9)
         Sleep(5)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```